# What is the correct scenario while using amazon S3 for image hosting website?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, amazon-s3, hosting

I am developing an images hosting section in a website, and I am going to use amazon s3 for hosting the images there.

I will get the images the user upload, save on the server, then send a copy to S3, then later when the user browser ask for that Image I get it from the S3.

Like that I will have 2 versions from all images, and like that I feel confused about the benefit from S3, as I will not save space on the server and also will get some of the server bandwidth to send images to S3.

So is this is the correct way to do it? If you did something like this before, what will be the best scenario in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to keep a copy on your local hosting. I believe S3 deals with disaster recovery (unless you don't use "reduced redundancy storage") - http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DataDurability.html . Copying the data one more time won't hurt, but you won't really benefit from this.
Also S3 is very scalable and it is likely to be better accessible than your hosting.
Even if you decide to store the pictures on the local server as well, don't worry too much about the traffic to send them to S3, it will be most probably insignificant compared to the OUT traffic you will have from S3. Besides you don't pay for the IN traffic to AWS.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the idea is to *only* store a copy on S3. Why would your server need to keep a copy if it's in S3, after all?

Optionally you might want to save a copy in a disaster recovery system somewhere - this is something you'd want even if you had the one server, though, so you still have two copies either way.